# Low FPS rate on Chrome Androïd with simple Canvas2D Game

Tags: javascript, android, performance, canvas, frame-rate

I'm currently developping a simple 2D canvas video game and while I was testing performance, I noticed that there is a very disappointing frame rate on Androïd Chrome (about 45fps).

About one out of two frame breaks. And I cannot see what in my call stack is creating the performance issue. As you can see on the performance capture, the task lasts less than 4ms (which is under the 16ms of refreshing)

[image: Screenshot of performance viewer]

Zoomed :

[image]

And here is the sample code of the game loop... with almost nothing in it (I removed all the game stuff) :

```
Game.loop = function(){ 
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        
    requestAnimationFrame(Game.loop);
}
```

Comment: `setTransform` is probably the culprit. Why do you always reset the transform every frame?

Comment: You are not proving enough information to help measuring performance. May you can check this article to provide more information about how to use Chrome's Profile properly to find the call stack and the mos expensive operations at your game: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: @catgirlkelly setTransform is a better alternative used to avoid save() and restore() but it's actually not the problem. I've just removed it and the fps rate is no more around 40.

Comment: @JanCássio The call stack is very thin as there is almost nothing in the loop (it last less than 3ms)... So I supposed that it was a well known issue between Android chrome, canvas 2d and requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I think i will try with a new file and a very simple game loop to identify the bug. Is canvas 2D using GPU acceleration on mobile ?

Comment: Good. So consider comment some lines of your code, start by the higher level til the lower. It will help you figure out what part of you code is more expensive.

Comment: Here is the demo test : 
https://siriusbelt.alwaysdata.net/_stack/stack.php
It's a very simple loop, and it seems that every canvas command make go down the fps rate to 45 instead of 60...